# how to force a child class to use a method from the parent class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, interface, object-oriented-analysis

I have a class that uses a method that needs to be used by all the child classes. How can I force all the child classes to use that method? Throw interfaces?

Edit: i am using php. What I mean is this:
I have a method called toLower(), i have a database where all the columns are uppercase and everytime I fetch an object from the database I need to use toLower() method to make the object properties lowercase. I want to be able to force the client user to use that method whenever he fetches a result.

Comment: What do you mean by "force"? Must the child classes not be able to override a certain method?

Comment: What do you mean by throw interfaces?

Comment: You have not mentioned which language you are using - and without context your question does not make much sense, please clarify.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but I think using stored procedures on your database would fit your answer. See here to know how to lower case in SQL: http://www.brettb.com/SQL_Help_Change_Lower_Upper_Case.asp

Answer (score 0):

When you are using PDO to interface with the Database, you can use `PDO::ATTR_CASE` to force column names to a specific case specified by the `PDO::CASE_*` constants, e.g.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER
));
```

If you want to do that inside your mapping layer for some reason, simply use

- [`array_change_key_case`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php) — Returns an array with all keys from input lowercased or uppercased.

on the returned rows before you map your columns to your objects:

```
$row = array_change_key_case($row, CASE_LOWER);
```

Not sure what to answer about your remaining question parts. For a better answer please update your question and show the related code bits.